# Find Lyapunov function for $\dot{x} = -\sin(x)$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, stability-in-odes

$$\dot{x} = -\sin(x)$$

1. Find the fixed points and also find out if it is attractive or repelling
2. Find Lyapunov function for each of the attractive fixed points.

I thought:

1. Fixed points are $n\pi$ and the even integers are stable and thus attractive and the uneven integers are unstable and thus repelling. 0 is an unstable critical point.
2. How can I find a Lyapunov function? I couldn't find a general appliable theorem when i searched the web.

Lyapunov stability: nearby trajectories remain close for all time

Are the following steps correct ? :

a) Find fixed points

b) Linearize the system (find Jacobian)
here it is simply $J = [-\cos(x)$ $ 0] $ if I'm not mistaken

c) Choose $V(x)$ to be... $\cos(x)$ maybe and find partial derivative so $\sin(x)*\dot{x}$..

Can someone please show me how to solve question 2. (that is if I did 1. correctly) Thanks

Comment: So, no question?

Comment: The general idea, coming from physics (potential energy) is that if $\dot x = -F'(x)$, then $F(x)$ is something to look at.

Comment: In general there is no algorithm for constructing Lyapunov functions, However, if you notice that if you choose $V(x) = \cos{(x)}$, then $V'(x) \cdot (-\sin{(x)}) = -(\sin^2{(x)}) $. Can you take it from there?